# Changing column values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of shape:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 1 |
| 0.22 | 0 |
| 0.89 | 0 |
| 0.12 | 1 |
| 0.54 | 0 |
| 0.11 | 1 |

Assume that this dataset is sorted based on time and `df.iloc[1]` is before `df.iloc[2]`. Also assume that Col2 is binary.
What i would like to do is change the value of each Col2 sample as follows:
df.iloc[i]['Col2'] is 1 if any of the next 2 samples is 1 in the dataframe, else it is 0. Leave the last 2 elements of the dataframe unchanged
For example the result here would be:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 0 |
| 0.22 | 1 |
| 0.89 | 1 |
| 0.12 | 1 |
| 0.54 | 1 |
| 0.11 | 1 |

What i have done so far:

```
for i, j in df.iterrows():
   if i<df.shape[0]-2:
       df.iloc[i]['Col2'] = max([df.iloc[j]['Col2'] for j in range(i,i+2)])
```

I think the code works correctly but since my dataset is very large it takes too much time to run. Is there a more elegant and computationally friendly solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `shift` to get shifted versions of the test column and then add them up and threshold.  I've done this below, with an intermediate column `c` left in so that you can see how it works. The final column `at_least_one` should be what you're looking for, if I'm not mistaken.

edit: I just tried this with a million rows instead of 10, and it took 2.6 ms.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(10), 'b':np.random.choice([0,0,1],10)})
test['c'] = test.b.shift(-1) + test.b.shift(-2)
test['at_least_1'] = (test.c > 0).astype(int)

test
>>> 

    a   b   c     at_least_1
0   0   0   0.0     0
1   1   0   0.0     0
2   2   0   0.0     0
3   3   0   1.0     1
4   4   0   1.0     1
5   5   1   1.0     1
6   6   0   1.0     1
7   7   1   0.0     0
8   8   0   NaN     0
9   9   0   NaN     0
```